# ImportError: cannot import name <Module>

Tags: python, django, pythonpath

I have an app in Django,

```
apple/
|-- README.md
|-- __init__.py
|-- buildmaps.py
|-- diffengine.py
|-- models.py
|-- parser.py
|-- runner.py
|-- serializers.py
|-- tests.py
|-- urls.py
|-- views.py
```

I have 2 files,

**parser.py**

```
class TestAbc:
   ...
```

**buildmaps.py**

```
class TestXyz:
   ...
```

From within buildmaps if I try to import from parser TestAbc. I get,

```
from apple.parser import TestAbc

importError: cannot import name TestAbc
```

However I can import

```
from apple.parser import *
```

which works but the class is not imported.
Also if I try to import from within python manage.py shell it imports fine.

Any ideas.

Comment: your application inside `apple` package? and `parser` module is inside `apple` package ? correct?

Comment: it is working? or still you have any issue related to code?

Comment: Can you try printing `apple.parser.__file__`, and verify that it is the correct path?

Comment: I've tried to reprocude your error (https://github.com/f3anaro/so-28295498) ... but in the repo I can import the `apple.parser.TestAbc`. It would be nice, if you take a look :)

Comment: Yep this looks ok. But I cannot figure out why this is having issue on my machine.

Comment: In the end I moved the class to a different file and it worked (??)